# What is the material leaking out of my plumbing drain stack?

Tags: pipe, sewer

This has been happening since about a month after we moved and we noticed a fluid leaking out of this pipe. It seems to be a sewage pipe. Whenever we flush, we can hear the water running down this pipe that there's this weird liquid the keeps leaking out from around the pipe itself. Does anybody know what this is?

[image: pipe image]

Comment: that is what you flushed down the toilet ... it is unclear why you had to ask

Comment: mmmmm... sewage. Probably a plumber pulled that clean-out to snake the sewer line at some point, and didn't tighten it down very well when done. Get a wrench and snug it down a little more.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a drain/sewage pipe. What comes out of a sewage pipe??? Sewage!
Get some rubber gloves and a dust respirator and clean that pipe and plug, a wire brush would be a good start. Then remove the plug and clean the threads on both surfaces. Apply some pipe dope to the threads and screw the plug back on to the pipe. Tighten as necessary to stop the leak.
That plug looks like it might be PVC so if the threads are destroyed, you might have to replace it.

Comment: On a large clean-out plug like this, **Pipe Joint Compound,** also called **Pipe Dope,** will be easier to use than tape.

Comment: Would one normally put a PVC plug into what looks like a cast iron clean out? If replacement is necessary, and the clean out is cast iron, it would probably be a good idea to replace it with a cast iron plug - it'll cost a few bucks more but last, essentially, forever.

Comment: Yes, on large and coarse threads you'd use thread compound, not PTFE tape. It all looks like cast iron to me, but I'd have no concerns about using a PVC plug (if a replacement is warranted for some reason).

Comment: And a PVC plug has a slight amount of give (compared to cast iron) so it would better fit into any imperfections in the existing cast iron pipe....resulting in a better seal.